# Laravel postgres sql Case Insensitive Like

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, psql, case-insensitive

I have a postgres sql query in Laravel :

```
$_query = Article::join('users', 'articles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->select('users.*','articles.*');                           
if( array_key_exists('title', $parameters) && $parameters['title'] != '' )       
        $_query->whereRaw( " LOWER(nbl_region_ref.region) like LOWER('%?%')", array( trim($parameters['region']) ) );
$result = $_query->get();
```

Output/Error: 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42P18]: Indeterminate datatype: 7 ERROR:  could not determine data type of parameter $2'

Tried Query builder :

```
$_query= DB::select("select users.*, articles.* from articles")
                ->join('users', 'articles.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
if( array_key_exists('title', $parameters) && $parameters['title'] != '' )       
            $_query->where( "articles.title","ILIKE", array( trim($parameters['title']) ) );
    $result = $_query->get();
```

Output : Invalid FROM.. table not found

Tried ILike (Based on a similar question without a join)

```
$_query = Article::join('users', 'articles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->select('users.*','articles.*');                           
if( array_key_exists('title', $parameters) && $parameters['title'] != '' )       
                $_query->where( "articles.title","ILIKE", array( trim($parameters['title']) ) );
```

Output : Empty array

Tried :

```
 $_query = Article::join('users', 'articles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                        ->select('users.*','articles.*');                           

$_query->where( function ( $_queryTemp ) use ( $parameters ) {
if( array_key_exists('title', $parameters) && $parameters['title'] != '' )       
            $_query->whereRaw( " LOWER(nbl_region_ref.region) like LOWER('%?%')", array( trim($parameters['region']) ) );
});
```

Output/Error: 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42P18]: Indeterminate datatype: 7 ERROR:  could not determine data type of parameter $2'

I have to make a case-insensitive search query based on the input parameter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your third attempt looks like what you want. Based on your first and last attempt, it looks like you want your search text wrapped in '%'. Since you didn't do this for your third attempt, I'm assuming that's why your query didn't find any results (empty array).

Query should be:

```
$_query = Article::join('users', 'articles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select('users.*','articles.*');
if (array_key_exists('title', $parameters) && $parameters['title'] != '') {
    $_query->where('articles.title', 'ILIKE', '%'.trim($parameters['title']).'%');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot patricus..can't believe missed that

Comment: This saved me as well. Thanks @patricus

Answer (score 6):

Unlike MySQL, PostgreSQL has two options for pattern matching: `ILIKE` and `LIKE`.

- `ILIKE` is for **case in-sensitive**
- `LIKE` is for **case sensitive**

If you want to query based on in-sensitive value, like `title`. You should use `ILIKE`.

```php
// app/Models/Article.php
public static function getByTitle($title){
    return self::where('title', 'ilike', "%${title}%")->orderBy('title', 'asc')->get();
}
```

More on PostgreSQL docs :

> The key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match
> case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the
> SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension.
>
> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/functions-matching.html

Answer (score 4):

Using `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE` solved it for me