# How to search incasesensitive query in the Postgresql database using Laravel query builder?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

I want to create a filter. But I am facing case-sensitive problem. I have tried with my below code. But It didn't work. I have got error 'call undfiend lcase'.

```
 $type = strtolower($type);
 $name = strtolower($name);
 $users  = DB::table('daftar.bank_list AS uc')
     ->leftJoin('users.users as u','u.bank_id','=','uc.id')
     ->when($type, function ($query, $type) {
         return $query->where('LCASE'('uc.type'), $type);
     })
     ->when($name, function ($query, $name) {
         return $query->where('LCASE'('uc.name'), $name);
     })
     ->get();
```

My database is Postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$type = strtolower($type);
$name = strtolower($name);
$users  = DB::table('daftar.bank_list AS uc')
    ->leftJoin('users.users as u','u.bank_id','=','uc.id')
    ->when($type, function ($query, $type) {
        return $query->where('uc.type','ILIKE', '%'.$type.'%');
    })
    ->when($name, function ($query, $name) {
        return $query->where('uc.name','ILIKE', '%'.$name.'%');
    })
    ->get();
```

You can search by `ILIKE` query.

Comment: Note that your `ILIKE` comparison is _not_ the same thing as the equality expression in the OP.  You may want to remove the `%` wildcards.

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888874/laravel-postgres-sql-case-insensitive-like

Answer (score 1):

Postgres uses the `LOWER()` function, not `LCASE`.  Also, if you want to call a native Postgres function, you should be using `whereRaw`:

```
$users = DB::table('daftar.bank_list AS uc')
    ->leftJoin('users.users as u', 'u.bank_id', '=', 'uc.id')
    ->when($type, function ($query, $type) {
        return $query->whereRaw('LOWER(uc.type) = ?', [$type]);
    })
    ->when($name, function ($query, $name) {
        return $query->whereRaw('LOWER(uc.name) = ?', [$name]
    })
    ->get();
```